# How to add ScrollController to SliverList flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I can add ScrollController to a ListView. I was trying to do the same for SliverList but I realized there is no parameter to add a controller. Is there any other way I can achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView/controller.html

Comment: So it's rather in the CustomScrollView. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You cannot add it to a SliverList, you can however, add the controller to your parent CustomScrollView. The SliverList comes inside the CustomScrollView and should give you the effect you want.
As you can see in the screenshot, you can add a controller to your CustomScrollView.

[image]

Comment: Excelllent! Works like a charm.